# Difference in row size for a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account]
(
     [AccountId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [RowVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
     [Deleted] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Account_Deleted]  DEFAULT ((0)),
     [CurrentBalance] [decimal](19, 4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
     [ExtrasCurrentBalance] [decimal](19, 4) NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),

     CONSTRAINT [PK_Account] 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AccountId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

As per the logic in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/estimate-the-size-of-a-heap

```
Row_Size = Fixed_Data_Size + Variable_Data_Size + Null_Bitmap + 4
```

So my row size should be

```
(6+8+1+9+8)+3+4 = 39
```

But when executing this query

```
DBCC SHOWCONTIG ('dbo.Account') with tableresults
```

I see `MinimumRecordSize` and `MaximumRecordSize` as 52.

[image]

So how did we get a value of 52 bytes?

Thanks,
Pavan

Comment: The article you linked is about storage space for a heap, what you posted as your table is not a heap. and curious how you came up with the number you have.

Comment: You should be using DATALENGTH to get the number of bytes. Or you could look at the documentation about storage bytes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql

Comment: @SeanLange But still that doesn't give me the accurate value. If possible could you please elaborate how we got 52

Comment: I wouldn't use SHOWCONTIG like this. Never even thought of that. But it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have row versioning active in your database, then it makes sense.

You can check with this query:

```
SELECT name, is_read_committed_snapshot_on, snapshot_isolation_state
FROM sys.databases;
```

If either flag is on for the database you are working with then you have row versioning, which by itself adds 14 bytes to your row size.

So 52 breaks down as follow:

- 7 bytes for overhead (number of columns, internal flags, null bitmap, row size, etc);
- 14 bytes for row versioning;
- 31 bytes for your columns (int = 4 bytes, timestamp = 8 bytes, bit = 1 bit per bit, rounded up to whole bytes, decimal(19) = 9 bytes);